# Flutter Release Mode: Background Service Stop Issue and Wallpaper Code Not Executing

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm facing a distinct issue with my Flutter background service in release mode. While the background service initiates successfully, it doesn't respond to stop requests. Furthermore, the wallpaper-setting functionality, which functions flawlessly in debug and profile modes, does not execute at all in release mode.

BackGround service

```
Timer? timer;
StreamSubscription? streamSubscription;

Future<void> initializeService() async {
  SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  int savedSec = pref.getInt('duration') ?? 0;
  bool servicesOn = pref.getBool('serviceOn') ?? false;

  if (savedSec == 0 || !servicesOn) return;

  try {
    final service = await getWallpaperService();
    if (!(await service.isRunning())) {
      service.startService();
    }
  } catch (e) {
    debugPrint(e.toString());
  }
}

@pragma("vm-entry-point")
void onStart(ServiceInstance service) async {
  if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
    service.on("setAsForeground").listen((event) {
      service.setAsForegroundService();
    });
    service.on("setAsBackground").listen((event) {
      service.setAsBackgroundService();
    });
  }

  service.on("stopService").listen((event) {
    service.stopSelf();
    timer?.cancel();
    streamSubscription?.cancel();
    timer = null;
  });

  if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
    setWallpaper();
  }
}

Future<FlutterBackgroundService> getWallpaperService() async {
  var permissionStatus = await Permission.notification.request();
  if (!permissionStatus.isGranted) {
    throw 'Notifications permissions not granted';
  }
  await initializeNotifications();
  final service = FlutterBackgroundService();
  service.configure(
    androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
      onStart: onStart,
      autoStart: false,
      isForegroundMode: true,
      foregroundServiceNotificationId: 8888,
      notificationChannelId: 'WallpaperService',
      initialNotificationContent:
          'This will allow PicMingle to update your wallpapers',
      initialNotificationTitle: 'Wallpapers service is running',
    ),
    iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(),
  );
  return service;
}

void setWallpaper() async {
  SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String homeAlbum = pref.getString("homeAlbum") ?? '';
  String lockAlbum = pref.getString('lockAlbum') ?? '';

  streamSubscription ??= Screen().screenStateStream?.listen((event) {
    if (event.name == 'SCREEN_OFF') {
      changeWallpaper(lockAlbum, WallpaperManager.LOCK_SCREEN);
    }
  });

  int savedSec = pref.getInt('duration') ?? 0;
  if (timer != null) return;
  timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(minutes: savedSec), (t) async {
    await changeWallpaper(homeAlbum, WallpaperManager.HOME_SCREEN);
    setWallpaper();
  });
}

Future<void> changeWallpaper(String album, int screenType) async {
  if (album.isNotEmpty) {
    String path = await getAlbumsPath;
    var dir = Directory("$path/$album");
    if (!dir.existsSync()) return;
    var obj = AlbumModel.fromDir(dir);

    Random random = Random();
    int index = random.nextInt(obj.allImages.length);
    File file = obj.allImages[index];

    WallpaperSetter setter = WallpaperSetter();
    setter.setWallpaper(file.path,  screenType);
  }
}

Future<void> initializeNotifications() async {
  final notificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  var androidInitSettings = const AndroidInitializationSettings(
    '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
  );
  var iosInitSettings = const DarwinInitializationSettings();

  final initSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: androidInitSettings, iOS: iosInitSettings);
  await notificationsPlugin.initialize(initSettings);

  var channel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'WallpaperService',
    'Wallpaper Service Channel',
    description: 'Channel for Wallpaper Service',
    importance: Importance.defaultImportance,
  );
  await notificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}
```

Wallpaper code

```
class WallpaperSetter {
  WallpaperSetter._privateConstructor();

  static final WallpaperSetter _instance =
      WallpaperSetter._privateConstructor();

  factory WallpaperSetter() {
    return _instance;
  }

  Future<void> setWallpaper(String path, int location) async {
    try {
      await WallpaperManager.setWallpaperFromFile(path, location);
    } on PlatformException catch (e){
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```